# Trying to run python script within Django within Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to run my python script that uses some models defined inside django which is then within a docker container. I use the following command:

```
sudo docker-compose -f production.yml run django python manage.py shell < send.py
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
IndentationError: unexpected indent
  File "<console>", line 1
    stats = grp_px.calc_stats(dropna=False)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
  File "<console>", line 1
    st = stats.render_perf(key=key)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
  File "<console>", line 1
    perf_list.append([key, st.render()])
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
  File "<console>", line 1
    send_mail(html_message=render_to_string('fund_vs_peers.html', {'perf_list': perf_list}),
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
  File "<console>", line 1
    message='',
    ^
```

Basically, I get an indentation error each line of my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously your `send.py` is misformed.

Comment: Try using [`commands`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) instead of piping a .py file